# Unable to rename directory using Google Cloud SDK getting 404: No such object:buket/olddirname

Tags: directory, filesystems, google-cloud-storage, rename

I am trying to rename a directory of google cloud using the SDK. I am getting error message of `404 No such object:buketname/previousDirName`. Renaming a file works fine but only facing issue in renaming folder.

Here is the code i am using:

```
          if(file_exists(dirname(__DIR__) .'/vendor/autoload.php')){
        
            $selected_bucket = 'BucketName';
            $key_file = dirname(__DIR__).'/authkey.json';
            $client = new StorageClient([
                'keyFilePath' => $key_file,
            ]);
            $bucket = $client->bucket($selected_bucket);
            $endpoint = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/'. $selected_bucket;
            if(isset($subfolder)){
                $adapter = new GoogleStorageAdapter($client, $bucket, $subfolder.'/');  // code to list specific subfolder of the bucket
            } else {
                $adapter = new GoogleStorageAdapter($client, $bucket);
            }

            $filesystem = new Filesystem($adapter, Array ( "url" => $endpoint ));

            // rename a file
            $filesystem->rename('filename.txt', 'newname.txt'); // works fine

            // rename a directory
            $response =  $filesystem->rename('developer', 'developer123');

            print_r($response);
            die();
    }
```

I tried to debug in the sdk but nothing found. I searched the issue if someone faced the same issue but didn't found any working solution. I found one but the solution was in `gsutil`.

Please please suggest me what I am missing in case of renaming directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage does not not have the concept of "folder", there are only buckets that contain storage objects (flat namespace) and the meaning of "/" is really imposed by clients (and client libraries). As such, folders can't be renamed atomically and thus you would need to rename each of the contained files, by using the [gsutil mv](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv#renaming-groups-of-objects) command as you have already figured out, like:

> gsutil -d mv gs://my-bucket/folder1 gs://my-bucket/folder2

- The -d option will cause it to output the sequence of requests gsutil generates to do the rename and additional debug info needed.
- In addition, you could try using the [-I option](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#options), which reads the file list from stdin and is supported with the mv command, as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv#options).

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/copying-renaming-moving-objects#rename) you may find an example of code samples as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I looked at the links you provided. Can you please help me a bit more. In the [example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/copying-renaming-moving-objects#code-samples_1) of `Renaming an object`, there is `$newObjectName`. Will it be the new name with which the current object is going to be replaced? Will `$newBucketName` and `$newObjectName` both will have same value e.g. `developer123`?

Comment: bucket != object. You cannot change the name of the bucket since it is globally unique during all its lifecycle.